# NetworkX Graph object not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, networkx

I was trying to monkey patch the NetworkX Graph object without typing out

```
networkx.Graph.method_name = method_name
```

for every single method I defined.  I tried this (minimal version):

```
import networkx

class _GraphExtended (networkx.Graph):
    def is_nonnull(self):
        return bool(self.nodes())

for key in _GraphExtended.__dict__:
    nx.Graph[key] = _GraphExtended[key]
```

and I got the error "'type' object is not subscriptable" for every key.  How do I monkey patch all methods using a loop?

Comment: What do you expect `_GraphExtended[key]` to be?  Both `nx.Graph` and `_GraphExtended` are classes.  It looks like you're treating them as dict.

Comment: @Joel I think I was expecting to access class methods `MyClass.my_method` in the same way I would access them via an object of the class: `my_class_instance.my_method`.  Then, because I needed to use a variable instead of hardcode a method name, I used square brackets: `MyClass[variable_containing_method_name]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis of your current approach

You are using subscript notation via the square brackets. Normally, you would type `my_object[key]`, which is translated *as a first approximation** into `my_object.__getitem__(key)`.

In particular, if the `type(my_object)` does not define the `__getitem__` attribute, then you effectively get an error that says that `type(my_object)` is not subscriptable.

In your case, `type(_GraphExtended) == type` holds true. Furthermore, the `type` class does not define any `__getitem__` attribute. Therefore, this is why you get the error message that `type` is not subscriptable.

*For the sake of completeness, a more accurate translation would be along the lines of: `object.__getattribute__(my_object, '__getitem__')(key)`.

## What you probably intended

What you probably intended was to set the `'method_name'` attribute of the `networkx.Graph` object. In general, this can be accomplished by using the `setattr` built-in function, as follows:

```
setattr(networkx.Graph, key, value)
```

Also, `_GraphExtended.__dict__` contains many more keys than what you intend to monkey patch. You may be able to filter out those that start and end with double underscore, but I am neither confident that this filter works under all circumstances nor confident that it is forward-compatible with Python.

## Pitfalls to monkey patching

Firstly, monkey patching may break forward-compatibility with the networkx library. There is no guarantee that future versions of networkx will avoid the same method names that you have chosen to monkey patch.

Secondly, monkey patching will prevent you from writing reusable code. It is no longer possible for other developers to reuse your convenience function(s) unless they themselves monkey patch their code, and there may likely be unforeseen reasons that prevent this from being possible.

## Practical advice

***Don't Do It.*** I must warn you that the monkey patching library code is very poor style, and should only be used as a last resort in the world of programming (e.g. if it were to have a positive and measurable effect on business revenue or a related resource thereof such as development time).

What are the underlying concern(s) that you wish to solve? I would be willing to followup with alternative solutions that address each underlying concern you may have.

Also, have you considered the simple approach of defining a helper module containing helper functions, such as:

```
# Module graph_utils

def is_nonnull(graph):
  return bool(graph.nodes())
```

## Other notes

Python already has a convention to handle boolean contexts: anything considered empty should also be considered False. For example, according to networkx documentation, the `Graph` class defines a `__len__` method that returns the number of nodes. Because of `__len__`, Python allows using `Graph` objects in contexts where a `bool` is expected. For instance,

```
graph = networkx.Graph()

print(not graph)  # Prints True iff len(graph) == 0

if graph:
  print('Graph is nonnull.')
else:
  print('Graph is null.')
```